# a specific way to use max()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, gaps-and-islands

I have DateTime, total, material, and Mix columns.

This equipment runs Mix A for x amount of hours, then switches to Mix B for x amount of hours. Then switches back to Mix A.

I would like to have a query that is just:

```
Select max(total), material, mix 
from database 
group by material, mix
```

however I would need to catch the fact that Mix A was ran twice and only 1 value would be recorded and I wouldn't know how much material was used in the one that was skipped.

Is there a way to look at Max(total), then look for a new max every time the mix or material changes? (not actual different mix / material but when it actually changes from Mix B to mix A.

*Edit to show what data looks like*

```
Timestamp                  Mix           Material          Tons  
2017-02-08 07:49:25.000    MixA          Mat1              30.05
2017-02-08 07:50:25.000    MixA          Mat1              30.27
2017-02-08 07:51:25.000    MixA          Mat1              30.50
2017-02-08 07:52:25.000    MixA          Mat1              30.76
2017-02-08 07:53:25.000    MixA          Mat1              31.01
2017-02-08 07:58:25.000    MixB          Mat1              0.1
2017-02-08 07:59:25.000    MixB          Mat1              0.8
2017-02-08 08:00:25.000    MixB          Mat1              1.3
2017-02-08 08:01:25.000    MixB          Mat1              2.0
2017-02-08 08:02:25.000    MixB          Mat1              2.5
2017-02-08 08:10:25.000    MixA          Mat1              0.1
2017-02-08 08:01:25.000    MixA          Mat1              0.5
```

So, before the first record shown above the machine was running for some amount of time. Then they switched mixes, ran, then switched back and ended production for the day.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to find the amount of material used, because the Tons column is a running total and I can't just sum it. MAX() would be really simple, however I would miss the second run of Mix A.

Comment: can you put a sample of what your data looks like right now and how you would like it to look.

Comment: Updated post to show it neatly

Comment: are you trying to find the sum of the material used for that day for each mix or sum of material used for that day for a given material within a given mix?

Comment: Sum of material used for that day for each mix IE: a sum of Mat1 used in MixA and a sum of Mat1 used in MixB. Then if I wanted the whole day I could just sum those values

Comment: one more question so on the very first record you have 30.05 tons of material should we take that into account for the sum of Materials for that mix?

Comment: @Neal, Please show us the final result that you expect to receive based on your sample data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond again yesterday, the day got busy and away from me. the first record of 30.05 tons is just where I started to keep it short before that there would be records recorded every minute that would be increasing up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `gap-and-islands` to me.

**Sample data**

Note, I added `Mat2` to show that we need to partition by it and fixed the timestamp of the last entry.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ts datetime2(0), Mix varchar(50), Material varchar(50), Tons float);

INSERT INTO @T (ts, Mix, Material, Tons) VALUES
('2017-02-08 07:49:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 30.05),
('2017-02-08 07:50:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 30.27),
('2017-02-08 07:51:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 30.50),
('2017-02-08 07:52:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 30.76),
('2017-02-08 07:53:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 31.01),
('2017-02-08 07:58:25', 'MixB', 'Mat1', 0.1  ),
('2017-02-08 07:59:25', 'MixB', 'Mat1', 0.8  ),
('2017-02-08 08:00:25', 'MixB', 'Mat1', 1.3  ),
('2017-02-08 08:01:25', 'MixB', 'Mat1', 2.0  ),
('2017-02-08 08:02:25', 'MixB', 'Mat1', 2.5  ),
('2017-02-08 08:10:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 0.1  ),
('2017-02-08 08:11:25', 'MixA', 'Mat1', 0.5  ),
('2017-02-08 07:49:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 30.05),
('2017-02-08 07:50:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 30.27),
('2017-02-08 07:51:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 30.50),
('2017-02-08 07:52:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 30.76),
('2017-02-08 07:53:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 31.01),
('2017-02-08 07:58:25', 'MixB', 'Mat2', 0.1  ),
('2017-02-08 07:59:25', 'MixB', 'Mat2', 0.8  ),
('2017-02-08 08:00:25', 'MixB', 'Mat2', 1.3  ),
('2017-02-08 08:01:25', 'MixB', 'Mat2', 2.0  ),
('2017-02-08 08:02:25', 'MixB', 'Mat2', 2.5  ),
('2017-02-08 08:10:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 0.1  ),
('2017-02-08 08:11:25', 'MixA', 'Mat2', 0.5  );
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ts
        ,Mix
        ,Material
        ,Tons
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY ts) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material, Mix ORDER BY ts) AS rn2
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        ts
        ,Mix
        ,Material
        ,Tons
        ,rn1
        ,rn2
        ,rn1 - rn2 AS GroupNumber
    FROM CTE_rn
)
SELECT
    Material
    ,Mix
    ,MAX(Tons) AS MaxTons
    ,MAX(ts) AS MaxTS
FROM CTE_Groups
GROUP BY
    Material
    ,GroupNumber
    ,Mix
ORDER BY
    Material
    ,MaxTS
;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+------+---------+---------------------+
| Material | Mix  | MaxTons |        MaxTS        |
+----------+------+---------+---------------------+
| Mat1     | MixA | 31.01   | 2017-02-08 07:53:25 |
| Mat1     | MixB | 2.5     | 2017-02-08 08:02:25 |
| Mat1     | MixA | 0.5     | 2017-02-08 08:11:25 |
| Mat2     | MixA | 31.01   | 2017-02-08 07:53:25 |
| Mat2     | MixB | 2.5     | 2017-02-08 08:02:25 |
| Mat2     | MixA | 0.5     | 2017-02-08 08:11:25 |
+----------+------+---------+---------------------+
```

You can sum it up further to add `31.01` and `0.5` for `Mat1` if you need it. Just add one more `GROUP BY Material, Mix`. The question is not really clear what the result should be.

### How it works

Run the query step-by-step, cte-by-cte to understand how it works.

"Gaps and islands" is a classic problem. When a `Mix` changes, the "island" is followed by a "gap".

`CTE_rn` calculates two sets of row numbers. The difference between them is the number of the group (`CTE_Groups`).

```
WITH
...
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Groups
ORDER BY Material, ts;
```

Produces

```
+---------------------+------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-------------+
|         ts          | Mix  | Material | Tons  | rn1 | rn2 | GroupNumber |
+---------------------+------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-------------+
| 2017-02-08 07:49:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 30.05 |   1 |   1 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:50:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 30.27 |   2 |   2 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:51:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 30.5  |   3 |   3 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:52:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 30.76 |   4 |   4 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:53:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 31.01 |   5 |   5 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:58:25 | MixB | Mat1     | 0.1   |   6 |   1 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 07:59:25 | MixB | Mat1     | 0.8   |   7 |   2 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:00:25 | MixB | Mat1     | 1.3   |   8 |   3 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:01:25 | MixB | Mat1     | 2     |   9 |   4 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:02:25 | MixB | Mat1     | 2.5   |  10 |   5 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:10:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 0.1   |  11 |   6 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:11:25 | MixA | Mat1     | 0.5   |  12 |   7 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 07:49:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 30.05 |   1 |   1 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:50:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 30.27 |   2 |   2 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:51:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 30.5  |   3 |   3 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:52:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 30.76 |   4 |   4 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:53:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 31.01 |   5 |   5 |           0 |
| 2017-02-08 07:58:25 | MixB | Mat2     | 0.1   |   6 |   1 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 07:59:25 | MixB | Mat2     | 0.8   |   7 |   2 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:00:25 | MixB | Mat2     | 1.3   |   8 |   3 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:01:25 | MixB | Mat2     | 2     |   9 |   4 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:02:25 | MixB | Mat2     | 2.5   |  10 |   5 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:10:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 0.1   |  11 |   6 |           5 |
| 2017-02-08 08:11:25 | MixA | Mat2     | 0.5   |  12 |   7 |           5 |
+---------------------+------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-------------+
```

Then we simply `GROUP BY Material, GroupNumber, Mix` to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Put this here just to show what was being used so you have idea on how much you helped clean this up and optimize it.
The current way to do this is:

```
SELECT D1.[Day],
  D1.[TimeStamp],
  D1.[Material],
  D1.Source,
  CASE WHEN D1.[RunTotal] - D2.[RunTotal] >= 0 
    THEN D1.[RunTotal] - D2.[RunTotal] ELSE 0 END AS [Tons]
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) rownum, 
  [TimeStamp], 
  cast([TimeStamp] AS date) [Day], 
  MIN(CASE Equipment WHEN 'Bin1' THEN CAST([Run Total] AS decimal(18, 3)) END) AS [RunTotal], 
  MIN(CASE Equipment WHEN 'Bin1' THEN Material END) AS [Material], 
  'Bin1' AS Source
FROM  Plant_Production.dbo.Data  
WHERE Equipment = 'Bin1'
GROUP BY [Timestamp]) D1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) rownum, 
    [TimeStamp],     
    cast([TimeStamp] AS date) [Day], 
    MIN(CASE Equipment WHEN 'Bin1' THEN CAST([Run Total] AS decimal(18, 3)) END) AS [RunTotal],
    MIN(CASE Equipment WHEN 'Bin1' THEN [Material] END) AS [Material], 
    'Bin1' AS Source
  FROM Plant_Production.dbo.Data
  WHERE Equipment = 'Bin1'
  GROUP BY [TimeStamp]) D2 ON D1.RowNum - 1 = D2.RowNum AND D1.[Day] = D2.[Day]
```

They do that for every Bin location and sum up all the values for a date range.   The way you suggested seems not only a lot faster of a query but also a lot cleaner.